# Storing user data in custom database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am making web inventory management app. My question is how I should store data like items in inventory of every user. Should I every users items in one table or create new database for every user?

Comment: You certainly do not need to create a new database for every user, one table is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to store each user's inventory in separate database because it will be worst nightmare to manage hundreds of users and their databases in future. I would suggest to store all users inventory data in inventory table and use UserId as a reference or foreign key of this table derived from users table.